# SQL - Slow SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a sql query (see below) for wordpress which is taking around 4-5secs to get results. It gives all order ids which have a product/variation id in it.

I want to make it more fast, any help?

```
SELECT p.ID order_id 
    FROM wp_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items i ON p.ID=i.order_id 
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta im ON i.order_item_id=im.order_item_id 
WHERE im.meta_key IN ('_product_id','_variation_id') 
    AND im.meta_value IN ('703899','981273','981274','981275') 
    AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed') 
GROUP BY p.ID HAVING COUNT(p.ID)>1 
ORDER BY p.post_date desc 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Above query `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

Comment: for optimization we need create tables explain see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you join when you only want to select IDs from wp_posts anyway?

```
SELECT p.ID order_id 
FROM wp_posts p 
WHERE p.post_status = 'wc-completed'
AND p.ID IN
(
  SELECT i.order_id
  FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items i
  JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta im ON im.order_item_id = i.order_item_id
  WHERE im.meta_key IN ('_product_id','_variation_id') 
    AND im.meta_value IN ('703899','981273','981274','981275') 
  GROUP BY i.order_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Now let's think about how the DBMS can address this. It can look for posts with status 'wc-completed', if there are only few such rows and then check whether they represent an order with more than one of the desired items. This would ask for these indexes:

```
create index idx1 on wp_posts(post_status, id, post_date);
create index idx2 on wp_woocommerce_order_items(order_id, order_item_id);
create index idx3 on wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta(order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value);
```

Or it could look for the desired products, see whether an order contains more than one of them and then check whther this relates to a post with status = 'wc-completed'. That would ask for these indexes:

```
create index idx4 on wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta(meta_key, meta_value, order_item_id);
create index idx5 on wp_woocommerce_order_items(order_item_id, order_id);
create index idx6 on wp_posts(id, post_status, post_date);
```

We don't know which way the DBMS will prefer, so we create all six indexes. Then we look at the explain plan to see which are being used and remove the others. Maybe the DBMS even sees no advantage in using indexes here at all, but I find this unlikely.

Comment: @Vaibhav Gupta: I should add that your original query would benefit from the same indexes. I am suggesting `IN` (or `EXISTS`) here, because you only want to lookup the order details. Putting criteria in the `WHERE` clause is where it belongs in my opinion and can make a query easier to understand. But the rewriting probably won't make much of a difference in regards to speed. The indexes will.

Comment: `SELECT p.ID order_id 
FROM wp_posts p 
WHERE p.post_status = 'wc-completed'
AND p.ID IN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT i.order_id FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items i
  JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta im ON im.order_item_id = i.order_item_id AND im.meta_key IN ('_product_id','_variation_id') AND im.meta_value IN ('703899','981273','981274','981275')
)
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20;`

Just curious to ask, can you explain the diff between this query with yours (except GROUP BY)? 

Thanks!

Comment: and thanks for the indexes... now my own query running much faster just bcoz of indexex!

Comment: Yep, while we *can* write bad queries, we usually don't. It's indexes that speed up our queries, not rewriting the queries :-) As to the query you posted: My query gets you orders containing more than one of the products, your query gets you orders containing at least one of the products. (The `DISTINCT` is superfluous in your query by the way; the `IN` clause doesn't care whether it finds an entry one time or a thousand times.)

Comment: @VaibhavGupta - The indexes needed for this answer are probably installed for you by this Plugin:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can try doing is trimming what data you fetch.

That means:

1. Not fetching fields that you don't need/check
2. Implementing our constrains before joining

```
SELECT 
    p.ID order_id 
FROM 
    (SELECT id, post_status, post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'wc-completed') p, 
    (SELECT order_id, order_item_id FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items) i,
    (
        SELECT 
            order_item_id,
            meta_key,
            meta_value 
        FROM 
            wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
        WHERE 
            meta_key IN ('_product_id','_variation_id')
            AND meta_value IN ('703899','981273','981274','981275')
    ) im
WHERE 
    p.ID = i.order_id
    AND i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id 
GROUP BY 
    p.ID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(p.ID)>1 
ORDER BY 
    p.post_date desc 
LIMIT 
    0, 20
```

---

**Edit:**

If Inner joins are necessary, you can try:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID order_id 
FROM 
    (SELECT id, post_status, post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'wc-completed') p 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT order_id, order_item_id FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items) i 
ON 
    p.ID = i.order_id 
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            order_item_id,
            meta_key,
            meta_value 
        FROM 
            wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
        WHERE 
            meta_key IN ('_product_id','_variation_id')
            AND meta_value IN ('703899','981273','981274','981275')
    ) im
ON 
    i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id 
GROUP BY 
    p.ID
HAVING 
    COUNT(p.ID)>1 
ORDER BY 
    p.post_date desc 
LIMIT
    0, 20
```

<sub>**ps*** I hope my syntax is correct ˙ my SQL is quite rusty</sub>

Comment: It usually makes no difference whether to apply criteria in a subquery and join this or just join the table and apply that criteria then. The DBMS's optimizer sees what we want and chooses the best way, anyway. It is even supposed that mere joins are easier for the optimizer to see through, so the OPs query may even benefit from this as opposed to your query where you kind of try to force an approach on the optimizer. And comma-separated joins were used in the 1980s until explicit joins where introduced into standard SQL in 1992. So, OP's query is superior in two regards in my opinion.

Comment: You have posted a second query where you suppose to have changed something vital. You haven't. Both queries use inner joins. The first one with an ancient syntax. The second one with an up-to-date syntax.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I didn't posted the Inner-Joined in the beginning. I didn't knew about DBMS's optimizations so, I'm glad I learned something. Lastly, since the local university's fashion is avoiding IJ keywords, I'm also thankful for reading these comments.

Comment: Is the "p.ID IN (...)" being cached or recreated each time, in the approach you suggested?

Comment: The DBMS is free to do one thing or the other. With `IN` we rather suggest the list is created once as a lookup for all posts, whereas with `EXISTS` we would express this as loop through the posts and check the subquery. But the two do the same thing, so the DBMS's optimizer can choose whatever approach it prefers. A perfect optimizer would choose the same execution plan for both these queries (i.e. for `IN` or `EXISTS`), but well a *perfect* optimizer would even choose the same plan for the joins and the thus forced aggregation of course, for again this leads to the same result.

Comment: That your university favours comma-separated joins over explicit joins is awful. I mean, the new syntax has been in place for almost thirty years now. And it was invented for a reason. Comma-separated joins are less readable, i.e. the queries harder to maintain, they are more prone to errors, and there is no standard old syntax for outer joins. Make this a rule: Never use comma joins, always use `[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: (You may notice that I am suggesting to also dismiss right outer joins and natural joins. The former can make a query extremely hard to read and the latter can lead to working queries becoming suddenly invalid. Don't use them. This is not only me thinking so, by the way. Many experienced database developers have the very same opinion.)